# Spring Cloud: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /brokers/ids

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I am using `Spring-cloud-stream` for kafka implementation. Spring cloud properties are:

```
spring.application.name=services
spring.stream.bindings.output.destination=testTopic
spring.stream.bindings.output.content-type=application/json
spring.stream.bindings.kafka.binder.zkNodes=localhost
spring.stream.bindings.kafka.binder.brokers=localhost
```

But I got error that zookeeper can not be started.

```
Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 10000
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:1223) ~[zkclient-0.7.jar:0.7]
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:155) ~[zkclient-0.7.jar:0.7]
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:129) ~[zkclient-0.7.jar:0.7]
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.createZkClientAndConnection(ZkUtils.scala:89) ~[kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.apply(ZkUtils.scala:71) ~[kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils.apply(ZkUtils.scala) ~[kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder.createTopicAndPartitions(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:438)
```

Then installed zookeeper on laptop and started it. But now I am getting another error which is:

```
Failed to start bean 'outputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkNoNodeException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /brokers/ids
    Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /brokers/ids
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:111) ~[zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6-1569965]
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51) ~[zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6-1569965]
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getChildren(ZooKeeper.java:1472) ~[zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6-1569965]
```

Spring Boot version: 1.4.4
Spring Cloud version: Camden.SR5

What is the issue here?

Comment: Seems for me we have to use Kafka-specific repackaged Zookeeper, not original: https://kafka.apache.org/downloads

Comment: @ArtemBilan Where would I find Kafka-specific repackaged Zookeeper?

Comment: https://kafka.apache.org/downloads. When you download their distribution it contains Zookeeper and Kafka server.

Comment: Yeah...just did that. In the bin folder ran `./zookeeper-server-start.sh -daemon ../config/zookeeper.properties` still getting the same error.

Comment: Do you use Kafka server from the same distribution?

Comment: I am using the `spring-cloud-stream` library. Do I need to start kafka server separately?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155594/discussion-between-himanshu-yadav-and-artem-bilan).

Comment: Yes, of course. SCSt just uses Apache Kafka as messaging broker. But that isn't its responsibility to start Kafka server

Comment: Do you need to start RabbitMQ if you use Rabbit Binder instead? Do you need to start IBM MQ to to have your JMS client working? What is the difference with Kafka? What makes you to think that it is somehow different? Please, read Apache Kafka docs carefully.

Comment: Got your point. What are the kafka services I need to start to make it work? I have started `kafka-server` and `zookeeper-server` but still getting the same error.

Comment: I will go through the documentation and get back to you.

Comment: No-no. Don't come back, please! ;-) I'm not good in Kafka and I really don't know what that error means. Sorry, but I feel useless for you because my ideas didn't help you.

Comment: Maybe you need to delete Kafka and ZK logs to start from the clean page?